# How do I fix this error with node.js and node-imagemagick: Error: Command failed: execvp(): Permission denied?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

Im getting this error:

```
Error: Command failed: execvp(): Permission denied
```

When I do a simple node-imagemagick script:

```
im = require('imagemagick');
im.identify.path = '/tmp/node_thumbs/';
im.identify('cool.jpg',function(err,features){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(features);
});
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission denied is from trying to launch the ImageMagick command, not in the process of executing it.

If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick), identify.path is "Path to the identify program." In this case, you're redefining the path to the executable as /tmp/node_thumbs/, which presumably is not the executable.

You probably simply want:

```
var im = require("imagemagick");
im.identify('/tmp/node_thumbs/cool.jpg',function...
```